# Why my app vibrates only when the usb cable is connected to the PC?

Tags: android, permissions, chronometer, vibration

Im my app. I have to make vibrations in time intervals  defined by the user.

Basically it has a chronometer that makes the device vibrating when it is reached the defined time.

I have two issues:

- 1) When the app is in backgound, the chronometer continues counting, but the vibration stops.
- 2) I've added the WAKE_LOCK permission in my manifest, and the interesting is that the app vibrates in background, but only when the device is connected to the pc through the USB cable.

The permissions is this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Any idea to fix this?

Thank you!